# link html css and an image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add actions to this image 
[image]
So when the user hovers over red dot, some information appears, or when clicks (modal from bootstrap appears). I am using bootstrap, and spreading divs over the image don't give normal result. I want it to be responsive. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe by checking the coördinations the cursor is located to, relative to the picture. If it's in the right spot then do the popup?

Comment: this should require javascript? and a lot of work no?)

Comment: you are probably better adding div overlays at certain points then adding the hover for that overlay EDIT: someone already answered with that lol

Comment: do u have jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting red dots in photoshop and then adding them using pure html (I made buttons with background image of red dots) then I placed this dots randomly on the roadmap

Answer (score 0):

there should be a onhover method for javascript on the html dom.

```html
<div id="point1" onmouseover="doHover('point1', true);" onmouseout="doHover('point1', false);"></div>
```

Comment: so how this is supposed to link html with image?)

Comment: when you add div's over each point and use it as "invisible buttons", wich you can hover

Comment: i know it :) the problem is to fix div over red dots

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a problem with the divs?

```js
function doHover(id, bool) {
  var obj = document.getElementById("hoverPoint"+id);
  if(bool) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor="green";
  }else {
    obj.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  }
}
```

```css
.hoverPoint {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .6;
}

#hoverPoint1 {
  top: 130px;
  left: 135px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUTxI.png" style="width:777px; height:292px" />
<div class="hoverPoint" id="hoverPoint1" onmouseover="doHover(1,true);" onmouseout="doHover(1,false);"></div>
```